# Два блока посредине на flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

Казалось бы - простая структура блоков, которые должны визуально вылазить за пределы wrapper (оборачивать wrapper-ом не обязательно, указал для наглядности) и растягиваться на узком экране до 1000px на всю ширину. Но увы, ничего не выходит.
[image: flex блоки]

При этом, блоки должны оставаться зависимыми друг от друга, т.е. растягиваться по высоте контента одного из блоков. Также не понятно, как лучше сделать промежуток в середине 20px, margin-ом или отдельным div-ом?

Фрагмент кода, который выполняется все условия за исключением промежутка в середине и блоки не вытягиваются на всю ширину экрана, как на картинке выше. Есть ли решение у этой задачи?

```html
<div class="container" style="background:gray;width:100%">
  <div class="wrapper" style="margin:0 auto;display:flex;width:100%;max-width:1000px;">
    <div class="block left" style="width:50%;padding:35px;background:#7e87ab">text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text</div>
        <div class="block right" style="width:50%;padding:35px;background:#83ab7e">text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Промежуток делается свойством gap. Текст надо обернуть блоком с ограничением на максимальную ширину. Максимальная ширина равна  1000px/2 - gap/2 - padding

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.container > div {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 35px;
}

.left {
    background: #7e87ab;
}

.right {
    background: #83ab7e;
}

.text {
    max-width: 455px; /* 1000px/2 - 20px/2 - 35px */
}

.text-left {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="text text-left">text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text</div>
    </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="text">text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```